# Highlighting menu item when id is in viewport

Tags: jquery, menu, highlight

Im trying to highlight menu items when the corresponding ID reaches the top of the page but I can't seem to get the code to work. I think I know the issue - but I don't know how to fix it.

I think the issue is in the last line where its adding the ID to the link. The problem is my link has the page name and not just the'#' so its not matching when it reaches to top of the page.

So how do I say add the id after the # but keep the link text before it (that will be different every time)?

```js
$('.navDropdownList a').on('click', function() {
 'use strict';
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
 'use strict';
    $('.target').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.navDropdownList a').removeClass('active');
            $('.navDropdownList a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navDropdownList">
  <li><a class="closeMobNav" href="thisIsThePage.html#section-1">Link text</a></li>
  <li><a class="closeMobNav" href="thisIsAnotherPage.html#section-2">Link text</a></li>
  <li><a class="closeMobNav" href="yetAnotherPage.html#section-3"><span>3.1</span>Link text</a></li>
</ul>


<section>
  <h2 class="target" id="section-1">Title</h2>
  <p>blar blar blar</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2 class="target" id="section-2">Title</h2>
  <p>blar blar blar</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2 class="target" id="section-3">Title</h2>
  <p>blar blar blar</p>
</section>
```

Comment: `thisIsThePage.html#section-1` does not match with `.navDropdownList a[href=#section-1]`, also, try to enclose the section in quote, something like `.navDropdownList a[href="#section-1"]`... and double check browser console for any js errors.

Comment: try `$(".navDropdownList a").attr("href", '#'+ id +'')`